# Replace literal \n with another literal \\n

Tags: python

I am struggling to replace the '\n' as literal not as break line to be '\n'
Example: the text is `mytext ='hello\n'` and I need the output to be like that
`mytext ='hello\\n'`

Comment: Have you tried using the [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cant commment but if I am understanding you right could you just do

```
mytext.replace('\n', '\\n')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact, It is solved by `replace('\\n', '\\\\n')`